# Как получить manifest

Tags: javascript, manifest

#### Описание

Создал у себя в сайте `mainfest.json`, задал все параметры как надо, подключил через `<link rel="manifest" />`. Теперь хочу добавить возможность проверки наличия обновлений и исходя из этого хочу получить свойство `version` в `manifest`.

---

Искал в интернете как получить данные из manifest, и все ссылки указывают на [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getManifest), где говориться, чтобы получить `manifest` используйте:

```js
browser.runtime.getManifest()
```

... и так же примечание внизу

> Это API основано на API Chromium chrome.runtime. Эта документация основана на runtime.json из кода Chromium.
> Информация о совместимости Microsoft Edge предоставлена корпорацией Microsoft и включена здесь под лицензией Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 United States License.

---

Так как у меня Microsoft Edge у меня не работает код из документации и вылетает с ошибкой, что `browser` не существует

> Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

---

Другими методами, чтобы получить манифест, нужно использовать `fs` из `node.js` или создать сервер...

#### Вопрос

Как можно получить `version` из `manifest` **только при помощи стандартной js**, без библиотек, серверов и тому подобного?